# Unknown host 'dl.google.com'. Adjust proxy : Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have recently downloaded Android Studio 3.4. I started a new project, but it doesn't work as it keeps giving the error : Unknown host 'dl.google.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

I have tried :
1. Using the latest Gradle Release (5.4)
2. Setting Auto-detect proxy
3. Deleting the gradle folder from - C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle and restarting Android studio after that so that new files are downloaded by android Studio itself.

This is from my build.gradle file :

```
buildscript 
{
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies 
{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects 
{
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any issue, try and search for possible solution before asking directly. You will be surprised that there has been solution to your question. Having said that, the issue is not with your gradle script but with Android Studio settings.

For windows, go to:

**File > Settings > *Appearance & Behavior* > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option *Auto-detect proxy settings***

On Mac it's under:

**Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour... etc**

you can also use the test connection button and check with *google.com* to see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

For first time running an app, it needs internet connection. Next time onwards it works without that error.
This is my observation.